# Ukrainian passport renewal

Tags: passport-renewals, ukraine, biometric-passports, ukrainian-citizens

I am looking for information on the renewal of an Ukrainian passport in Ukraine itself. Any information on the process, time taken, cost and especially the documents needed would be very helpful.

I tried looking for a website that contained all this information, but all I could find was the application for a new passport and nothing on renewals.

Also, I'm keen to know if a renewal of the international passport can only be done if the "internal" passport (the compulsory ID Ukrainian citizens all hold) is still active and not expired. If it needs to be active, it would be great to know how this passport can also be renewed, cost, time etc.

Comment: Do you speak Ukrainian?

Comment: unfortunately, i don't speak the language but only English. I am helping someone with this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All state services related to passports (and much more) can be done on the Web site of the **State Migration Service Of Ukraine**, https://dmsu.gov.ua/

[image: Web site of the DMSU]

Basically, requests to issue/renew both the ID and the International Passport are the first two services they offer (highlighted by mine).

Caveat: Make sure the language selector in the top right corner is set to Ukrainian. If it opens in English (like I did while trying to make an English-language screenshot), the set of services will be targeted foreign citizens.

The sequence is:

- request a time slot in electronic queue ¹;
- decide if you want it **biometric or not**, "fast" (1 week) or normal service (3 weeks) as the fee would be different;
- go to bank and pay the fee ²;
- visit the DMSU unit, provide ³ with your ID and receipt;
- make sure **your name is Latin-transcribed** the way you like it. I have the "old" way of transliteration, and I have many visas, accounts, and international contracts signed with that name, so I had to ask for the spelling like it used to be.
- wait for 3 weeks;
- pick up your passport.

¹) The online queue is a new feature so it is available in a limited number of DMSU units, mostly in Kyiv and several large cities. If you reside elsewhere, the site contains a list of DMSU units you have to visit personally.

²) **Don't use Web-banking** for payment because you would need a **stamped receipt**. Just go to any bank, say you're paying for passport, and they will know where to send the payment. Pay with cash and keep the receipt.

³) The complete list of documents, state fees, and other conditions is specified on [this page](https://dmsu.gov.ua/poslugi/dokumenti-dlya-vijzdu-za-kordon/vidacha-pasporta-gromadyanina-ukrajni-dlya-vijzdu-za-kordon.html) (in Ukrainian). Basically, an adult with no kids to be written in passport would need nothing more than local ID, an electronic or written request, and a receipt for payment the state fee.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @bytebuster! Very helpful. Am I correct that you still need an active ID to renew a passport, even if the current international passport is not yet expired?

Comment: @mVentures Yes, that's right. You can not bypass it because this is how the electronic system works. The system refused to issue me a new international passport because I needed either to paste a 45-years-old photo or (what I did) issue a new card-style ID. Only then I was able to apply for re-issue an int'l passport.

Comment: One last question @bytebuster: I am assuming that all of these applications can be done at their own offices rather than online? The person I am helping out isn't internet savvy and doesn't have a home internet either. In terms of processing, I am also assuming there is no discrimination between online or offline application and that they take the same amount of time? Once I hear from you, I shall surely mark it as complete :)

Comment: @mVentures, certainly, you can do everything in person. Just visit the DMSU unit, wait in line, and a clerk would help you out. The e-queue is for your convenience, not for any discrimination; it lets you avoid one visit and adds the ability to track your application.